# MySQL (and maybe PHP): Fill a new column with the host of a referer

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, http-referer

I have a table with a request log. In there is a column with referers. Now in order to see what domains refer the most requests I want to add a new column with the host of the referer.

That is no problem for the new entries but how do I update every row without an entry in the new row to have the host from the referer?

Is there an easy way to do this in MySQL or how di I solve it in PHP?

Comment: can you give us some sample database rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$oldRows = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM logs_requests WHERE host_ref = ''");
while($row = mysql_Fetch_array($oldRows))
{
 $host = parse_url($row['url_ref'], PHP_URL_HOST); 
 mysql_query("UPDATE logs_requests SET host_ref='$host' WHERE id='{$row['id']}'");
}
```

This php code fetch all the rows with empty `host_ref` field,
then it takes the host (www.domain.com) from the `url_ref` (www.domain.com/page/34.html) with the `parse_url` function.
After that , there's an `update` query which updates the host field.

NOTICE: Customize this code according to your db scheme.